# CMake treat file extension as if it were another file extension

Tags: cmake

How do I convince CMake that the file extension .swig is equivalent to .i?

How would I do this for other file extensions?

**Context**

I am using CMake (version 2.8, minimum 2.6) with Swig. If I set my swig interface file to having the .i extension, everything automagically works (I end up with a working .dll 'module' loadable from my target language interpreter tclsh). If I give it the .swig extension, CMake doesn't know what to do with it. I'd like to use one extension over another to abate syntax-highlighting-hell in my editor.

**Existing CMake file**

At the request of a commenter, here's mah' file:

```
find_package(swig REQUIRED)
include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

find_package(tcl REQUIRED)
include_directories(${TCL_INCLUDE_PATH})

set(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS -prefix thoughtjack -namespace)

link_directories(${OEEG_BINARY_DIR}/oeeg)

set(swig_interface_files native.i)
set_source_files_properties(${swig_interface_files} PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
file(GLOB_RECURSE native_source_files *.cpp *.c)

swig_add_module(thoughtjack_native tcl ${swig_interface_files} ${native_source_files})
swig_link_libraries(thoughtjack_native ${TCL_LIBRARY} oeeg)

file(GLOB script_files ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.tcl)
install(FILES ${script_files} DESTINATION opt/thoughtjack)
install(TARGETS thoughtjack_native DESTINATION opt/thoughtjack)

add_custom_target(
  thoughtjack
  DEPENDS thoughtjack_native
  SOURCES ${script_files}
)
```

The custom_xyz bit is there with the 'sources' bit and other decorations to tell CMake to make those available through the MSVS solution file. As stated, simply renaming the file from .swig to .i (as it's shown here) gives me a working, loadable, Tcl module that exports all the functionality I expect it to as per the native.(swig|i) file.

Comment: Can you paste your cmake content here? Also, could it be a solution adding a symlink with ".i" extension to your ".swig" file?

Comment: 1) Uh, sure, I can do that... but it's, like, almost the exact same thing from the tutorials. 2) The symlink isn't something I'd wanna do. I mean, I could, but I'm placing this into a source code repo and symlinks don't travel well. Also Windows hates symlinks unless they're made by this special command 'junction' I got off the web and that thing, while it works like a charm, has led to some weird side effects.

Comment: Do you have the problem both in Linux and Windows? Could it be that Windows doesn't like a file extension of 4 characters? (Try .swi, be aware that is taken http://filext.com/file-extension/SWi)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at the source code of `UseSwig` module, it's hard coded to only use filenames that matches `.i`, so you can't make it use something else.

Now, CMake can help you by adding a rule to copy `.swig` files to `.i` when it's needed:

```
set(swig_dot_swig_files your.swig files.swig)

foreach(item IN LISTS swig_swig_files)
    get_filename_component(itembase ${item} NAME_WE)
    add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${itembase}.i"
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${item}" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${itembase}.i"
        DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${item}"
    )
endforeach()
```

Then you can provide those files to `swig_add_module`

```
set(swig_dot_i_files your.i files.i)
swig_add_module(thoughtjack_native tcl ${swig_dot_i_files})
```

This solution has some good properties: for instance, a modification of the `.swig` will make the target rebuilt as there's a dependency from `.i` files to `.swig` files.

Comment: I guess beggars can't be choosers. >_<